# Recover deleted files EXT4

Tags: ext4

I made a mistake and rsynced with --delete.
How I can recover all the deleted files? Please Help. This machine has my PhD project.

i use testdisk /dev/vda1, select the disk,-> select NON Partitioned Media -> Advanced Filesystem Utilis

In Option "LIST" I can see the deleted files, but how can restores all deleted files? This machine is a server.
Thank you so much

Comment: Advice: Since this is IMPORTANT to you, don't flail around trying to do-it-yourself. Go straight to paid, professional data recovery.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Stop using the machine! The more you use the machine, the higher the chance that the disk space where the now-deleted files still reside, gets overwritten with new data. Then it would get harder.